# Use System.cmd to run Applescript

Tags: shell, elixir, phoenix-framework

I've got this function:

```
def run(id) do
  {_, status} = System.cmd "osascript", ["#{File.cwd!}/lib/script/test.applescript"], arg0: id
  {:ok, status}
end
```

I need to pass `id` to `osascript`. The shell equivalent would be: `osascript ~/lib/script/test.applescript 1` but I can't find the right option in Elixir. Everything returns an argument error, whether I do:

```
System.cmd "osascript", ["#{File.cwd!}/lib/script/test.applescript"], arg0: id
```

or

```
System.cmd "osascript", ["#{File.cwd!}/lib/script/test.applescript"], id
```

or

```
System.cmd "osascript", ["#{File.cwd!}/lib/script/test.applescript", id]
```

or

```
System.cmd "osascript", ["#{File.cwd!}/lib/script/test.applescript #{id}"]
```

How can I pass `id` to `System.cmd "osascript", ["#{File.cwd!}/lib/script/test.applescript"]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like it's gotta be a string is all:

```
{_, status} = System.cmd "osascript", ["#{File.cwd!}/lib/script/test.applescript", "#{id}"]
```

Works fine.